# No css on admin template after htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, url-rewriting

I have all my customers sites on a subdomain

```
customers.example.com/sites/customer_name
```

I have Them made a htacces URL rewrite, so the users only need to enter

```
customers.example.com/customers
```

Almost everything works fine, except when I go to a joomla backend

```
customers.example.com/customer_name/administrator
```

Then the CSS disappears. I don't know I it's a joomla error or just me doing something wrong

This is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 http://jdeweb.dk/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/$1/ [L]
```

Comment: Open the developer console, then go to the network tab. Does the css file give a 404 error or does it simply contain something else than you expected.

Comment: (I also suggest adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/` to your rule, as `http://example.com/nonexistingfile` will most likely become an Internal Server Error)

Comment: i think i have found the issue. I opened the develloper tools on google chrome, and found out that the path to the iris templates css file, is wrong. when i try to open the file on a new tab, the path says http://customers.example.com/customer_name/template/iris/css/template.css. When i add the administrator patj after customer_name, it works until i reload the page